# Picking numbers within a list with an interval of 60

Tags: list-manipulation, gathering

I have a list of integers from 1 - 400. I choose `n` random numbers with replacement from the list.

Here is an example:

```
list = 
  {5, 14, 15, 29, 38, 100, 112, 139, 156, 165, 195, 217, 
   228, 237, 249, 286, 320, 323, 325, 329, 335, 349}
```

If I have this list, the routine should find all the sublists with all the elements within 60 of each other

```
{{5, 14, 15, 29, 38}, {14, 15, 29, 38}, {15, 29, 38}, {29, 38}, 
 {100, 112, 139, 156}, {112, 139, 156, 165}, {139, 156, 165, 195}, 
 {156, 165, 195}, {165, 195, 217}, {195, 217, 228, 237, 249}, 
 {217, 228, 237, 249}, {228, 237, 249, 286}, {237, 249, 286}, {249, 286},
 {286, 320, 323, 325, 329, 335}, {320, 323, 325, 329, 335, 349}, 
 {323, 325, 329, 335, 349}, {325, 329, 335, 349}, {329, 335, 349}, {335, 349}}
```

`list`, in this case is sorted but that will generally not be true. I have a small program working now but it is less general and very slow. Can something be done here?

Here is my code:

```
between[l_] := Module[{}, 
    h = TakeWhile[l, # <= l[[1]] + 60 &];
    s = Drop[s, 1];
    h
]


s = Sort[RandomChoice[Range[400], 22]];
Table[between[s], {Length[s] - 7 + 1}]
```

Comment: You might need to explain a bit more clearly.  For example, what's wrong with {5, 14} as one of your sublists?  Posting your existing code always helps too.  `Split` and `Gather` are useful functions for this type of problem.

Comment: Hi wxffles; Basically between takes the first element of the list and finds the longest sequence it can. Then the front element is dropped from the global variable s. While it does not get all of them it hopefully gets the longest one which is what I was originally after.

Comment: It's generally a good idea to wait a while before accepting an answer. There may be more than one way to skin a cat

Comment: @David: Hi; I accepted because he exactly explained the command I had been fumbling with. However, Michael E2's routine is smoking on my machine. Fast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Nearest` with a suitable `DistanceFunction`, followed by a filtering using `Gather` can be used to pick the elements:

```
list = 
  {5, 14, 15, 29, 38, 100, 112, 139, 156, 165, 195, 217, 
   228, 237, 249, 286, 320, 323, 325, 329, 335, 349};

With[{
       nf = Nearest[list, DistanceFunction -> (If[ManhattanDistance[#, #2] <= 60, 0, 1] &)],
       filt = 
         Flatten[Gather[#, ManhattanDistance[#, #2] > 60 &] /. x : {__Integer} :> First@x] &
      },
  Composition[filt, nf] /@ list // DeleteDuplicates
]

(* {{5, 14, 15, 29, 38}, {100, 112, 139, 156}, {112, 139, 156, 165}, 
    {139, 156, 165, 195}, {165, 195, 217}, {195, 217, 228, 237, 249}, {228, 237, 249, 286}, 
    {286, 320, 323, 325, 329, 335}, {320, 323, 325, 329, 335, 349}}*)
```

If you want all the subsets, you can just call `Subsets` on each of the sublists above. However, as wxffles notes, your question is underspecified in this regard, because you seem to only consider subsets by dropping the first element successively and that too, only for certain lists.

Comment: Hi; Thanks, I was having trouble with an approach like that. Couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @bobbym Does your comment mean that this answer is what you wanted? Then you should accept it. Otherwise you should explain what is missing.

Comment: How do I accept it?

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way to get the output you desire, assuming you are looking for lists that are of length 2 or greater:

```
list = {5, 14, 15, 29, 38, 100, 112, 139, 156, 165, 195, 217, 228, 
   237, 249, 286, 320, 323, 325, 329, 335, 349};

DeleteCases[
 Pick[#, UnitStep[60 - (# - First@#)] & /@ #, 1] &@ NestList[Rest, list, Length@list - 2],
 _?(Length[#] < 2 &)]

(* {{5, 14, 15, 29, 38}, {14, 15, 29, 38}, {15, 29, 38}, {29, 38},
    {100, 112, 139, 156}, {112, 139, 156, 165}, {139, 156, 165, 195},
    {156, 165, 195}, {165, 195, 217}, {195, 217, 228, 237, 249},
    {217, 228, 237, 249}, {228, 237, 249, 286}, {237, 249, 286},
    {249, 286}, {286, 320, 323, 325, 329, 335}, {320, 323, 325, 329, 335, 349},
    {323, 325, 329, 335, 349}, {325, 329, 335, 349}, {329, 335, 349}, {335, 349}} *)
```

Alternatively, especially if the list is not sorted, then here's a slightly different way.

```
SeedRandom[1];
list2 = RandomInteger[{1, 400}, 22]
(* {258, 385, 135, 32, 337, 229, 96, 125, 138, 301, 324, 20, 76, 170,
    397, 10, 193, 318, 341, 175, 48, 115} *)

DeleteCases[
 Pick[list2, UnitBox[Rescale[list2, {#, # + 60}, {-0.5, 0.5}]], 1] & /@ list2,
 _?(Length[#] < 2 &)]

(* {{258, 301, 318}, {385, 397}, {135, 138, 170, 193, 175}, {32, 76, 48},
    {385, 337, 397, 341}, {258, 229}, {135, 96, 125, 138, 115},
    {135, 125, 138, 170, 175}, {138, 170, 193, 175}, {337, 301, 324, 318, 341},
    {337, 324, 341}, {32, 20, 76, 48}, {135, 96, 125, 76, 115},
    {229, 170, 193, 175}, {32, 20, 10, 48}, {229, 193}, {337, 324, 318, 341},
    {385, 397, 341}, {229, 193, 175}, {96, 76, 48}, {135, 125, 138, 170, 175, 115}} *)
```

Comment: Hi; Also very nice solutions that are working, thanks.

Comment: That is quite fast. +1

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I am a bit late, but here's another approach to the problem. To be honest, I do not have any idea how fast my approach is compared to the other ones presented, but I always wanted to use `Longest` in a "real-life" problem, so here we go:

Using your `list` (it must be **sorted**):

```
list = 
      {5, 14, 15, 29, 38, 100, 112, 139, 156, 165, 195, 217, 
       228, 237, 249, 286, 320, 323, 325, 329, 335, 349};
```

We apply a pattern and `ReplaceAll`:

```
list /. 
  {{___, #, Longest[y___], z_, ___} /; z <= # + 60 :> {#, y, z}, _ :> (## &[])} & /@ list
```

and get:

> {{5, 14, 15, 29, 38}, {14, 15, 29, 38}, {15, 29, 38}, {29, 38}, {100, 
>     112, 139, 156}, {112, 139, 156, 165}, {139, 156, 165, 195}, {156, 
>     165, 195}, {165, 195, 217}, {195, 217, 228, 237, 249}, {217, 228, 
>     237, 249}, {228, 237, 249, 286}, {237, 249, 286}, {249, 286}, {286, 
>     320, 323, 325, 329, 335}, {320, 323, 325, 329, 335, 349}, {323, 325,
>      329, 335, 349}, {325, 329, 335, 349}, {329, 335, 349}, {335, 349}}

I am not sure how much explanation you need to understand that. Maybe I highlight the central pattern:

```
 {{___, #, Longest[y___], z_, ___} /; z <= # + 60 :> {#, y, z}
```

This matches any sequence starting with some numbers or none, then the number `#` (this is a slot that will be filled with the elements of `list`, see the `Map` at the end of the code), then a sequence of numbers (called `y___`, where `y` can be "empty"), and finally `z`, followed by more numbers (or none). We condition `z` to be `<= # + 60`, as you desire. This pattern will be replaced by `{#, y, z}`, which is what you want, I hope. The second pattern is to get rid of the ones that do not match the first one, e.g. when we call 38 (it will be replaced by `##&[]`, a.k.a. `Unevaluated[Sequence[]]`.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a rather literal method:

```
near[a_, n_] :=
  DeleteCases[Pick[a, IntervalMemberQ[Interval[{#, # + n}], a]] & /@ a, {_}]

near[list, 60]
```

> ```
> {{5, 14, 15, 29, 38}, {14, 15, 29, 38}, {15, 29, 38}, {29, 38}, {100, 112, 139, 156},
>  {112, 139, 156, 165}, {139, 156, 165, 195}, {156, 165, 195}, {165, 195, 217},
>  {195, 217, 228, 237, 249}, {217, 228, 237, 249}, {228, 237, 249, 286}, {237, 249, 286},
>  {249, 286}, {286, 320, 323, 325, 329, 335}, {320, 323, 325, 329, 335, 349},
>  {323, 325, 329, 335, 349}, {325, 329, 335, 349}, {329, 335, 349}, {335, 349}}
> ```

This is appropriate for short lists which may be your application if "a list of integers from 1 - 400" is not merely an example, but very long lists will be slower.  Michael's method should be fast, but in version 7 I need this `SparseArray` trick for best performance:

```
near2[a_, n_] := 
 DeleteCases[#[[SparseArray[UnitStep[n + First@# - #]]@"AdjacencyLists"]] & /@ 
   NestList[Rest, a, Length@a - 2], {_}]
```

Comment: +1.  I'll have to remember `DeleteCases[.., {_}]` -- I was stuck thinking in terms of `Length`, which I knew would slow things down a little.