# Modifying a function so that it will take multiple conditions

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

How can I modify my function so that it will take a list of ordered pairs, and return just the pairs whose first value is greater than or equal to a given minimum and less than or equal to a given maximum value?

This is the initial code:

```
function2[list_, max_] := Select[list, # <= max &]
```

I know what to do for the order pairs. I just don't know how to use multiple conditions with `Select`.

Comment: In this case you can get away with a three argument form of `LessEqual` (e.g. `a <= b <= c`), but in general you can just use `And` for multiple conditions (e.g. `cond1 && cond2 && ...`)

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {{3, 4}, {5, 6}, {2, 9}, {1, 8}};
Select[data, 2.5 <= #[[1]] <= 3.5 &]
```

or

```
myselector[data_List, min_, max_] := 
   Select[data, min <= #[[1]] <= max &]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) does not auto-compile so where possible a vectorized approach will be faster.

```
data = {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}};

sel[v_, min_, max_] := UnitStep[(v - min) (max - v)]

mask = sel[data[[All, 1]], 2, 4]

Pick[data, mask, 1]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}
>
> {{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}}
> ```

This may be done in a single "line" if you prefer but I broke it down for intelligibility.

Performance comparison:

```
big = RandomInteger[9, {1*^6, 2}];

Pick[big, sel[big[[All, 1]], 2, 4], 1]   // Length // AbsoluteTiming

Select[big, 2 <= #[[1]] <= 4 &]          // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0367064, 300370}
>
> {1.10751, 300370}
> ```

Related questions:

- [How to find rows that have maximum value?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/900/121)
- [Select/Delete with Sublist elements?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2486/121)
- [Replace values which obey certain criteria](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9719/121)
- [Picking numbers within a list with an interval of 60](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28705/121)
- [Pick elements of largest absolute value](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31385/121)
- [Restoring the 1-to-1 correspondence between elements in two lists, where one list is used as a guide to prune elements from the other](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45381/121)

Answer (score 1):

David's answer is more efficient for your particular set of conditions, but in general you can chain conditions with `And` ( && ). In your case, it would look like this.

```
f[data_, min_, max_] := Select[data, Module[{u = First[#]}, min <= u && u <= max] &]
data = {{3, 4}, {5, 6}, {2, 9}, {1, 8}};
f[data, 2, 3]
```

> `{{3, 4}, {2, 9}}`

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {{3, 4}, {5, 6}, {2, 9}, {1, 8}};
```

Using [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html):

```
func[lst_, min_, max_] := True /. GroupBy[lst, min <= #[[1]] <= max &]
```

Using [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html)/[`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html):

```
rp[lst_, min_, max_] := 
 Reap[Sow[#, min <= #[[1]] <= max] & /@ lst, True, #2 &][[-1, 1]]
```

Then:

```
func[data, 2, 3]
rp[data, 2, 3]
```

both yield: {{3, 4}, {2, 9}}